# What is the different between axios & vue-axios?

Tags: vue.js

Can anyone provide the details about what is different between axios & vue-axios?
Which one we need to use? is both are require to use the api?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vue-axios` is just a wrapper, exposing `axios` to components as `this.axios`, `this.$http`, or `Vue.axios`. The main advantage to using this library is it saves you from having to import `axios` everywhere you use it (assuming your project has several references).

You don't need `vue-axios` to use `axios`. I would just install `axios` alone, and use that exclusively.

Comment: tony, thanks for clear this things. I have tried to use only axios package and its worked well. But i noticed that if i import this vue.use(axios) in main.js & if i use axios.get in component then it's show me 'axios' is not defined error so i have import this axios in same component file & its working. so is this thing is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You have to import `axios` in any file that uses it.

Comment: Don't do `Vue.use(axios)`. That does not do what you think (it doesn't make `axios` global).